# Anchor Points in Image Processing

Tags: opencv, image-processing, intel-ipp

I want to use filter functions in Intel IPP or OpenCV. There is an argument about the position of anchor points, and I don't know what they are or how I can use them.

What is an anchor point, and what is it for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say you use a filter with a kernel (or mask size or something similar). The anchor point defines how your kernel is positioned with respect to the pixel currently processed during the filter operation.

The anchor point is an `IppiPoint`, i.e. a struct with members `x` and `y`. This is the coordinate in the kernel of the currently processed pixel. Typically, it is set to the center, i.e. `kernelWidth/2` and `kernelHeight/2`.

*Originally, I claimed that the anchor point is a linear index. Sorry, that was wrong.*

Comment: What does anchor point Point(-1,-1) means? Normally it is written in place of a default anchor, but where exactly is it located in the Mat image?